# How to update OpenCV 3.4.2 to OpenCV 4 or latest stable version?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed OpenCV 3.4.2 successfully by following the tutorial given here:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/

Now, I would like to update to openCV 4 or the latest stable version.

Do I need to uninstall 3.4.2 first? 
If so, how should I uninstall it.

I am afraid to creating another virtual environment and installing version 4 or master package from github by following the same steps might create conflicts. Please advice.

Working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, python 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Python interface, I guess you can try something like `pip install opencv-python==4.0.0.21`. Note, you might need to run `pip3 install opencv-python==4.0.0.21` depending upon your pip version.

Comment: 1. No need to uninstall the previous version? 2. All this command will be run after activating the same virtual environment that I have installed the current OpenCV 3.4.2?

Comment: 1. It will override the existing version. 2. Yes, you need to run either of them depending upon your `pip`.

Comment: 1. So, whenever I need to update to any version, I just need to use the same method pip install opencv-python==VERSION? 2. How to know the latest stable version? From here, https://docs.opencv.org/master/index.html isn't the Version 4.0.1 is the latest stable? 3. Just in case, how to uninstall openCV completely which I have installed inside virtual environment ? Thanks

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. You can refer https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ 3. You can try `pip uninstall opencv-python`. 
Please, accept the answer if this fixes your problem.